# Tweepy Twitter PyBot not Retweeting Searched Hashtags

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using this template to try and retweet a post mentioning a certain hashtag. In this case, `#pleaseletthisbe`.

When a user mentions the Bot in a Tweet, the Bot will Retweet the Tweet. However, when users Tweet one of the Hashtags, nothing is posted.

I am using [PyBot](https://github.com/magsol/pybot) and [magicschoolbot.py](https://github.com/qadan/magic_school_bot/blob/master/magicschoolbot.py) for reference. Some code from the original file is commented out.

```
from pybot import PyBot
import re

class MagicSchoolBot(PyBot):

def bot_init(self):
    self.config['api_key'] = 'XXXX'
    self.config['api_secret'] = 'XXXX'
    self.config['access_key'] = 'XXXX'
    self.config['access_secret'] = 'XXXX'
    self.config['tweet_interval'] = 6 * 60
    self.config['search_interval'] = 2 * 60
    self.config['search_keywords'] = [
        '"#Pleaseletthisbe"',
        '"#pleaseletthisbe"',
        '"#PleaseLetThisBe"',
        '"#PLEASELETTHISBE"',
        ]

def on_tweet(self):
    pass

def on_mention(self, tweet, prefix):
    self.api.retweet(tweet.id)

def on_timeline(self, tweet, prefix):
    pass

def on_search(self, tweet):
    ## name = tweet.user.screen_name
    ## status = "@" + name + " with the Frizz? No way!"
    ## self.update_status(status, reply_to = tweet)
    match = re.search('', tweet.text)
    self.api.retweet(tweet.id)

def on_follow(self, friend):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = MagicSchoolBot()
    bot.run()
```

Comment: Your call to `re.search` passes an empty string as the regex parameter, which will match nothing. What are you aiming to match there?

Comment: I'm using the original file as reference. I am assuming it matches it with the `search_keywords` but i do not understand exactly how all of this works as of yet. I am interested in the one keyword `#pleaseletthisbe` and case sensitivity if it matters.

Comment: Looked through the source of PyBot. It seems odd that you put the `search_keywords` dictionaries first single quotes and then double quotes. Try removing the double quotes around the keywords and see if that helps.

Comment: The double quotes were sampled from the original template. I believe it is to compensate for the spaces in the phrases. The original template does work. I tried your method without any luck. I have not found much external information regarding PyBot.